# How to convert BIGINT to DATE in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to figure out how to convert and format a BIGINT field (i.e. 20200301) to a DATE type field using Redshift SQL. I was successful in getting the snippet below to work but I believe that returns a string and I need a valid date returned in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. I've tried several other version unsuccessfully. Thank you in advance.

'''to_char(to_date(date_column::text, 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want the `to_date()` part:

```
select to_date(date_column::text, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: This is hilarious I swear I did this and now it works. Thank you so much. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

When it is a timestamp we need the below code to convert into correct value.

```
select trunc(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + date_column / 1000 * INTERVAL '1 second')
```

Comment: We can use "from_unixtime(birth_dte)" as well